# Cassandra-1.1.6 and Hector-1.1.4 Api

Tags: java, cassandra, bigdata, hector

I got one column family in which I am using composite key. One of my composite key is UUID and the other key is string in which I am passing NULL value. Earlier, I was using hector-0.8.0 and my code was working fine. But now I want to upgrade my hector api to the latest version and its not accepting NULL value.

```
    try {
        Composite key = new Composite();
        key.addComponent("key1", strSerializer);
        key.addComponent(null, strSerializer);
        compMutator.addInsertion(key, "columnfamily", HFactory.createColumn("column1", "col2 value",HFactory.createClock(), strSerializer,strSerializer));
        compMutator.execute();
    } catch (HectorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above is the code which is working fine with hector-0.8.2 but giving error when I am using hector-1.1.4

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable able to add null component
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.addComponent(AbstractComposite.java:459)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.addComponent(AbstractComposite.java:447)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.addComponent(AbstractComposite.java:438)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.AbstractComposite.addComponent(AbstractComposite.java:429)
    at com.impetus.cassandra.hectorClient.Test.main(Test.java:29)

Can anyone help me out with this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Salman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composite key never be null,but if you want composite key null then try this,

```
try {
    Composite key = new Composite();
    key.addComponent("key1", strSerializer);
    key.addComponent("null", strSerializer);
    compMutator.addInsertion(key, "columnfamily", HFactory.createColumn("column1", "col2 value",HFactory.createClock(), strSerializer,strSerializer));
    compMutator.execute();
} catch (HectorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it is a bad practice

Comment: amit can u tell me what changes u made in my code. because i couldn't find any change.

Comment: this code was working fine with the older version. I tried some other ways thankfully got success after making some changes, instead of null I gave a blank string ("") and it worked with the latest version.

Comment: @user3568568 sorry i forget convert Null to "null",i edit answer please check it